# How to mark certain fields as NULLABLE or NOT NULLABLE in NestJS request validation with class-validator?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs

I am not able to determine in NestJS how to mark certain fields as NULLABLE or NOT NULLABLE in NestJS using the class-validator (Using PostgreSQL as db). See the example below.

Consider the following entity with **currency** as a `NOT NULL DEFAULT` field and **quantity** as a `NULL` field:

```
@Entity('product')
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({type: 'int'})
  price: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: Currencies,
    default: Currencies.USD
  })
  currency: Currencies;         // NOT NULL DEFAULT

  @Column({type: 'int', nullable: true})
  quantity: number;             // NULLABLE COLUMN
}
```

In the `POST` */product* request, the **currency** field is marked `@IsOptional` to exempt its absence from the request.

```
import { IsEnum, IsInt, IsOptional, IsString, Max, Min } from 'class-validator';
enum Currencies {
  USD = 'USD',
  INR = 'INR',
  GBP = 'GBP',
  EUR = 'EUR',
}

export class CreateProductDto {
  @IsString()
  readonly name: string;

  @IsInt()
  @Min(0)
  readonly price: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @IsEnum(Currencies)
  readonly currency: Currencies;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsInt()
  @Min(0)
  @Max(100)
  readonly quantity: number;
}
```

In the `PATCH` */product* request, all the fields are marked as `@IsOptional` using `PartialType`.

```
import { PartialType } from '@nestjs/mapped-types';
import { CreateProductDto } from './create-product.dto';

export class PatchProductDto extends PartialType(CreateProductDto) {}
```

Using the above-stated validation logic, I am facing the following issues:

1. For the create request, for the `NOT NULL DEFAULT` field - **currency**, the `@IsOptional` should ideally allow absent values but also allows `null`, which results in an *Internal Server Error*.
2. For the update/patch request, all fields are marked as `@IsOptional`, and sending `null` for the value for the NOT NULL field - name, results in an *Internal Server Error*.

Comment: Why don't you create `dto`s for each of your request methods? without extending from `PartialType`

Comment: Even if I do that, how would I mark any field as Nullable or Not Nullable? The @IsOptional decorator accepts both null and undefined.

Comment: @AliSherafat Entity is Not DTO and vice versa. They Originally have two different jobs

Comment: @Heartbit you're right. but I want to consider code reuse in entity and DTO because any change in entity class should be applied in DOTs and this is what I want to prevent.